# Redirecting a URL based on first 2 letters in its URL alias

Tags: .htaccess

So I have a problem in which I'm attempting to redirect a URL based on whether or not it begins with a certain few letters or numbers.  I'm needing to redirect a site visitor if the first 2 of the trailing URL begins with "A2" or "a2", remove the first 2 of the URL and then replace the "A2" or "a2" with a specific directory path.

So here's a specific example to clarify.  If the user clicks on (or types in their browser's address bar)

```
http://www.example.com/A2d39g
```

or

```
http://www.example.com/a2d39g
```

they would automatically be redirected to

```
http://www.example.com/product/d39g
```

Also worth nothing, they individual typing in this URL will be reading it off a label in the mail, they won't always be clicking on a link.  I originally had thought of doing this through jQuery (note some of the solutions below), but I've modified this posting as I think it would be better to approach this through the .htaccess file.

Comment: dont quite understand. You want to do this when they click on the link? or when they arrive to a page? is it is the latter, this would be a server side function, unless you will have a page called 'A2d39g'

Comment: Hey Victor, I'm using a tiny URL script that we're needing to put in another directory, but we're attempting to remove the directory path from the URL.  Instead I'm trying to find a way for the jQuery to write a conditional statement that checks the first 2 values of the URL and if they match, redirect the user to the specified directory.  I'll update the posting to explain this a little more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution...I reposted the question slightly differently here and it was answered: [Redirect a URL based off it's first character with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879233/redirect-a-url-based-off-its-first-character-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

[**See a demo of the following here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/TpthY/)

The first thing we need to do is bind the `click` event and prevent the default behavior:

```
$('.redirMe').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Then, within this click function we'll perform a series of splits and substring divisions in order to test the code value.  Note that I assume the link is no more complicated than what you've given, that it will always be the root host followed by a simple alphanumeric code.

```
var th   = $(this).attr('href'), // get the href
    ah   = th.split('/'),        // split it up
    code = ah[ah.length - 1],    // grab the last value (the code)
    c2   = code.substring(0, 2), // grab the first two code chars
```

Then we'll `pop` the code off the end of the split `href` to get the host and test the first two characters converted `toLowerCase` to see if they match `a2`, and if so redirect to product, otherwise visit a 404 page:

```
redr = (c2.toLowerCase() == "a2") ?
       ah.join('/') + '/product/' + code.substring(2) :
       ah.join('/') + '/404;
```

You can then set `window.location.href = redr` to redirect!

Again, [here's sample code of the above](http://jsfiddle.net/TpthY/).

Comment: Hey mVChr, thanks so much for your response.  The only problem with using this solution is that it requires the class to be associated with the link ".redirMe".  I'll clarify that in the posting.  Thanks for providing your answer though...I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this kind of redirection with Apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Add something like this to your httpd configuration files:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/[aA]2(.*)$|^/(.*)[aA]2$ /product/$1
```

Comment: Hey Phssthpok, thanks for that info.  Question, I dropped that into my .htaccess file in the root directory and made sure it had permission 777 but it's not redirecting.  Not quite sure how to test this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this in JavaScript in a cross-browser manner; many browsers do not allow you to get the full URL from `window.location` in order to prevent malicious JavaScript  from tracking users. The best way to do this would be on the server side. If you want to do a redirection from JavaScript, you would probably need to send an AJAX request to a server and hope that the HTTP referer header indicated the page where it was coming from, so it could respond with the desired action.