# Redirect a URL based off it's first character with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

So I have a problem in which I'm attempting to redirect a URL based on whether or not it begins with a certain numbers.  I'm needing to redirect a site visitor if the first character of the trailing URL begins with the number "1", then I need to remove the number 1 of the URL and then replace the 1 with a specific directory path.

So here's a specific example to clarify.  If the user clicks on (or types in their browser's address bar)

```
http://www.example.com/1d39g
```

they would automatically be redirected to

```
http://www.example.com/product/d39g
```

Also worth nothing, they individual typing in this URL will be reading it off a label in the mail, they won't always be clicking on a link.  I originally had thought of doing this through jQuery, but I thought .htaccess would be the best way to approach this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Activate the mod alias, then add this into your .htaccess

```
RedirectMatch /1(.*)$ /product/$1
```